# Applying a function all values in an array

Tags: php

$jobs is an array retrieved from a DB query. `print_r($jobs)` shows:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 131
    [Title] => -bla-
    [Baseline] => lorem ipsum ...
    [Description] => <ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li></ul>
    [EventID] => 1008
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 132
    [Title] => -bla 2-
    [Baseline] => lorem ipsum lorem ipsum...
    [Description] => <ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li></ul>
    [EventID] => 1009
)
```

etc ...

Id like to run utf8_encode() on all values of these arrays. I'm not sure if I should use array_map, array_walk_recursive ? The output should not alter the names of the array keys so that I don't need to change anything in my template, so

```
<h1><?=$j['title']?></h1>
```

should still work, albeit utf8 encoded.

EDIT: I'm trying the following, no luck

```
function fix_chars($key, $value)
{
    return utf8_encode($value);
}

array_walk_recursive($jobs, 'fix_chars');
```

Comment: Use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: watch my answer. the & before the $item is crucial.

Comment: Basically, the difference between `array_map` and `array_walk` is that the former returns a new array, while the latter will change the array in place. What do you want?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

this should work:

```
<?php
function encode_items(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($jobs, 'encode_items');
?>
```

Comment: this changes the item of the array directly letting the key as it was

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example with [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function utf8_encode_array($array) {
    return array_map('utf8_encode', $array);
}

$encoded_array = array_map('utf8_encode_array', $your_array);
```

I don't know if there is a performance difference between `array_map` and `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: Thanks @Felix King I was also facing the same problem and now it solve `array_map('utf8_encode', $array);` work for me.